# Bind to remote form complete event

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Nprogress to show a loading state for ajax requests on my Rails app. I've accomplished to make it work with all normal ajax calls but I'm now having problems with rails remote forms.

I'm now using this bindings that works great in most cases.

```
$(document).bind('ajax:before', function(){
  NProgress.start();
}).bind('ajax:complete', function () {
  NProgress.done();
}).bind('ajax:success', function () {
  NProgress.done();
}).bind('ajax:error', function () {
  NProgress.done();
});
```

My problem is that my js response is replacing the form to show errors and that's what's causing the progress bar to never complete.

My question is if there's any other way to listen for a remote call to be completed or if there is a way to run a kind of after callback on every remote js reponses. Maybe some kind of layouts for js responses?

My js.erb response looks like this

```
$('.add-form').html("<%= j(render partial: 'partial/path') %>");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whaat!!! I just solved my problem with a layout!!!! :D It makes sense that they work the same way as html layouts but I was not sure it would work!

I just created a layout called `application.js.erb` with the following content:

```
<%= yield %>
NProgress.done();
```

And it just works! I'm really happy because this was exactly what I needed, a kind of a after callback.

There is no need to change anything else.